# Parameter list to a query string HTML Form

Tags: html, forms

```
<form name="input" action="/test/compare method="get">
<input type="checkbox" name="id" value="val1">val1<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="id" value="val2">val2<br/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I want a query string that looks like this:

```
/test/compare?id=val1,val2
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly as comma separated values, but you can get an array of values of all selected checkboxes as follows.

```
<form name="input" action="/test/compare" method="get">
    <input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="val1">val1<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="val2">val2<br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
// here you'l get array of id in $_GET and process according to your need
$ids=$_GET['id'];

$str=implode(",",$ids);  //array to comma separated values

echo $str;   //output will be checked checkbox values--> val1,val2
```

**EDIT:**

**ANOTHER SOLUTION USING JAVASCRIPT**

```
<form name="input" action="/test/compare" method="get">
    <input type="checkbox" name="id" value="val1">val1<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="id" value="val2">val2<br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>  
 <!-- load jQuery -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"> </script> 
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
          $("form[name=input]").submit(function(){   //bind onSubmit handler on page ready
              //get all field values
              var query="id="; //write here parameter name
              $("form[name=input] [name=id]:checked").each(function(i){ //it will check for all elements inside form with name "id"
                   query+=$(this).val()+",";
              });

              query=query.slice(0,-1); //remove last extra comma
              //redirect url by passing "query" as GET parameter
              window.location=$(this).attr("action")+"?"+query;
              return false;
          });
     });
 </script>
```

Comment: See the comment I made on jacobroufa's answer

Comment: That URL doesn't matter, you try `$_GET['id']` you'l get desired output. I've tested that code :)

Comment: I've never used PHP, so I dont understand where this code goes? Can I embed it like javascript in my html?

Comment: Yes, you can have javascript solution as well. Give me a moment. I'l update my answer

Comment: Awesome! There is a problem with a dangling , at the end of the list. I added query=query.slice(0,-1) before the redirect.

Comment: Yes, It was. But i tried to make is as simple as possible. so forgot about that. :)
Njoy, have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

You can make `name="id[]"` to make the form parameter an array, but aside from that I don't believe it's possible to do what you are asking. You should have unique values as form fields unless they are an array.

Comment: The resulting url is this: 

/test/compare?id%5B%5D=val1&id%5B%5D=val2

Comment: Right -- this can be used as an array in whatever language you use to process the form. See the answer with the PHP example, below.